# Why does time go from Eastern to Pacific on the Careers page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I am reading the bottom of [this page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products) and I just saw this:

> Have more questions?
>
> If you have questions about programmer job listings or how to hire developers, call our dedicated sales team at +1-877-782-2577, or email us at careers@stackoverflow.com. Our business hours are **Monday-Friday, 9 a.m. Eastern to 5 p.m. Pacific**.

That is a little confusing.

Does that mean that in both Eastern **and** Pacific time you are open from 9-5, or in EST you are open from 9am-8pm and in PST you are open from 6am-5pm?

Can the times be consistent and stay in one timezone?

Comment: And it would probably be a good idea to offer utc/gmt timezone too. I only have a rough idea that those are somewhere between -3 and -11..

Comment: Depends on Daylight Savings too. Right now Eastern is GMT -5 but in a couple of weeks it goes to GMT -4

Answer (score 4):

It is 9am-8pm EST.  I don't find it all that confusing in its current format and it's been that way for well over a year without prior complaint and it's also a fairly typical way of representing support hours simply without trying to GeoIP.

In any case, I'll bring it up with the team.

Comment: As for "fairly typical" I don't think so, taking two random major companies as example: [Philips](http://www.support.philips.com/support/contact/contact_page.jsp?userCountry=us&userLanguage=en) showing "Monday - Saturday 9:00 AM - 9:00 PM EST" and [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/contact) showing for example "Mon - Sun : 9am - 6pm (EST)" (need to click "phone" link first)

Comment: I think that's a pretty weird format. I'd state it in the time zone your main office is in and also converted to UTC, for those of us who didn't memorize US timezone offsets.

Comment: Each of our translated sites has office hours and phone number for the appropriate office to connect to.  Showing times in UTC is not likely to happen unless one of our offices falls in a location that primarily uses UTC.

Answer (score 4):

We talked about it and decided it was a little confusing, so we changed it to 9 a.m. EST to 8 p.m. EST. It will go live after the next push.